# Ruby: Get result of previous method in current method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods

The following illustrates my problem:

```
User.all.testing

def self.testing
    v = self
    v.group_by { |user| user.username = 'username' }
end
```

leads to:

> undefined method `group_by' for Class:0x8ca0558

However:

```
User.all.group_by { |user| user.username = 'username' }
```

works.

Comment: I don't think that `User.all.group_by(username: 'username')` does work? `group_by` is a method from `Enumerable` but it doesn't take any parameters, but can be called with a block e.g. `User.all.group_by { |u| u.username }`. It can be called as `User.all.group_by { ...` because the relation returned by `all` is implicitly converted into an array.

Comment: @mikej It does work. How am I able to call it from the `testing` method?

Comment: Sounds like maybe you have some gem that's adding extra functionality on your project?

Comment: You've defined your method as a Class method by defining it as `def self.testing`. Thus, when you call `self` inside of the method, it's referring to the `User` class itself, not an `instance` of the `User` class.

Comment: @mikej No, try this in your Rails console. I guarantee that it waorks.

Comment: @JamesMilani Yes, that's exactly my problem. How do I fix it?

Comment: If you are open to changing the method and how you call it, then you could write `def self.testing` as `v = self.all` and call it not as `User.all.testing`, but as `User.testing`. I imagine that would work...

Comment: @JamesMilani That would work, but would change the functionality of the method. Is there no way to make the current method work?

Comment: @jonhue I have been testing this from the console on a Rails 5.1.3 and there's no `group_by` method for me that takes parameters in the way you've used it. That said assuming that method _does_ work for you I've written an answer explaining how to achieve what you're after.

Comment: @mikej I'm sorry, I had a mistake replicating the method here on StackOverflow. It obviously has to be `group_by { |user| user.username = 'username' }`

Comment: All cool! mystery solved :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, I can't explain where this `group_by` method that accepts a parameter is coming from, but to make your `testing` method work the same as `User.all.group_by(username: 'username')` write it as

```
def self.testing
  all.group_by(username: 'username')
end
```

The use of `all` will create an ActiveRecord relation for you. Note that even though it says "all", if you do have any other scopes in effect these [will be carried across](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/1280ad6d19fa56e9bf6d6a261c1231326cb3d8c3/activerecord/lib/active_record/scoping/named.rb#L29). e.g. it would behave correctly for `User.where(some: value).testing`. If you call `testing` directly without any other scopes established i.e. `User.testing` then then default scope will be used.

Comment: Ah.. Didn't know that `all` carries across scopes!

Comment: @jonhue I've just updated the answer with a link to the relevant bit of the Rails source. Check it out - it's pretty interesting and logical.

Comment: Thanks for the reference! Makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

`self` is a kind of `ActiveRecord::Base` object, and thus doesn't have a `group_by` method. `group_by` is an Enumerable method. Perhaps you mean `group`, which is implemented in `ActiveRecord::QueryMethods`?

Comment: No, I actually mean `group_by`. I want to do the same as `User.all.group_by(username: 'username')`, but using the `testing` method. If `self` isn't the way to go, what is?

Comment: `self.all.group_by` assuming `self.class` is `User`

Answer (score 0):

`self.testing` means this is a class method and can be used like `User.testing` NOT `User.all.testing` because `User.all` returns active record relation.

Solution: Create scope in your model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  scope :testing, -> (username) { group_by(username: username) }
end
```

Now you can use `User.all.testing`

Comment: Why down voting? This answer has merit.

Comment: Class methods *can* be used for scopes so `User.all.testing` would be valid: http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/02/active-record-scopes-vs-class-methods/

Comment: `scope` is just a fancy way of building a class method with a little extra stuff and ["Using a class method is the preferred way to accept arguments for scopes."(http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments).

Comment: really nice and concise way of explaining it - thanks @muistooshort